# Win8.1 App - TryGetItemAsync freezing

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have problem with this code:

```
static public async Task<bool> isFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
        return item != null;
    }
```

If file is created, my program freezing (but not always!) in line `var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);`. File is in 100% good.

Comment: Show us the method calling `isFileExists`. Does it use `Result` or `Wait` when calling?

Comment: `if (!IsFileExists("Settings.xml").Result)  
{  
  // creating new file  
} else {  
  // read existing file  
}`

Comment: You need to post more code so we can see from where and how this function is being called. Are you calling from the UI thread and blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I read **exactly** http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html and add `.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)` to `var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName)` and work good.